# Change UIButton gradient color

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton

I use the following method to add some gradient effect to my IOS UIButton. I call it in viewController's `viewDidLoad`, works great, so far so good.

Now, I'd like to change the color of the button according to some user interaction. What I do is simply calling this method by different colors `(fromColor, toColor)` as input. The problem, the look of my button does not change. I tried to call `setNeedsDisplay`, but did not help.

Would you be so kind to help me? What I miss? There is should be some problem with layers, should be rested or something like that, but I could not find its proper way.

Update: By using setSubLayers instead of insertSubLayer color changes, but button title disappears.

```
+(void)setCustomButtonStyle:(UIButton *)button cornerRadius:(float) cornerRadius fromColor:(UIColor *)fromColor toColor:(UIColor *)toColor normalTitleColor:(UIColor *)normalTitleColor highlightedTitleColor:(UIColor *)highlightedTitleColor borderWidth:(float) borderWidth borderColor:(UIColor*)borderColor
{
    [button setTitleColor:normalTitleColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setTitleColor:highlightedTitleColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    CAGradientLayer *btnGradient = [CAGradientLayer layer];
    btnGradient.frame = button.bounds;
    btnGradient.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                          (id)[fromColor CGColor],
                          (id)[toColor CGColor],
                          nil];
    btnGradient.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    btnGradient.borderColor = [borderColor CGColor];
    [button.layer insertSublayer:btnGradient atIndex:0];

    CALayer *btnLayer = [button layer];
    [btnLayer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [btnLayer setCornerRadius:cornerRadius];
}
```

Comment: Are you using this same method to update the colours?

Comment: yes, i use the same method

Comment: OK, next question. This is in a class method. Which class is it in? Is it a category on UIButton?

Comment: I have some utils class with a few ui related methods, like this

Comment: Hmm... not ideal. You need a way to get hold of that layer. OK, will answer now...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are having here is that **1.** you are creating a new layer each time you are changing the colour and **2.** you are then placing that new layer underneath everything else so you can't see it anyway. (Think of putting a playing card at the bottom of the deck).

What you need to do is keep hold of the gradient layer and then update then instead of creating a new one.

You are probably best doing this in a **category** on `UIButton`.

Something like... `UIButton+GradientBackground` or something.

In the .h file give it a single function...

```
// Use CGFloat not float. Also user NSInteger not int.
// Always.
// Also, I have used modern Obj-C syntax. Use this too.

- (void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius
              fromColor:(UIColor *)fromColor
                toColor:(UIColor *)toColor
       normalTitleColor:(UIColor *)normalTitleColor
  highlightedTitleColor:(UIColor *)highlightedTitleColor
            borderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth
            borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor;
```

Then in the .m file you need to also give it a property...

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer;
```

Now in the function...

```
- (void)setCornerRadius:(CGFloat)cornerRadius
              fromColor:(UIColor *)fromColor
                toColor:(UIColor *)toColor
       normalTitleColor:(UIColor *)normalTitleColor
  highlightedTitleColor:(UIColor *)highlightedTitleColor
            borderWidth:(CGFloat)borderWidth
            borderColor:(UIColor *)borderColor
{
    [self setTitleColor:normalTitleColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [self setTitleColor:highlightedTitleColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    if (!self.grandientLayer) {
        // if it doesn't exist then create it and add it (only once)
        self.gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
        [self.layer insertSublayer:self.gradientLayer atIndex:0];
    }

    self.gradientLayer.frame = self.bounds;
    self.gradientLayer.colors = @[(id)fromColor.CGColor, (id)toColor.CGColor]; // use modern syntax
    self.gradientLayer.borderWidth = borderWidth;
    self.gradientLayer.borderColor = borderColor.CGColor;

    [self.layer setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [self.layer setCornerRadius:cornerRadius];
}
```

Notice that I have removed the button from the function name as this function will essentially be part of that UIButton's functions so `self` is the button you are changing.

You would call it like this...

```
[someButton setCornerRadius:5 fromColor:[UIColor redColor] toColor... and so on];
```

By doing this you only create that gradient layer once and you keep hold of it so that you can update it the next time round.

Answer (score 1):

### For first time add gradient layer, next time replace added gradient layer

#### Added `Category` as @Fogmeister thinks this can be used with category only

```
@interface UIButton (gradient)
   +(void)setCustomButtonStyle:(UIButton *)button cornerRadius:(float) cornerRadius fromColor:(UIColor *)fromColor toColor:(UIColor *)toColor normalTitleColor:(UIColor *)normalTitleColor highlightedTitleColor:(UIColor *)highlightedTitleColor borderWidth:(float) borderWidth borderColor:(UIColor*)borderColor;
@end

@implementation UIButton (gradient)

 +(void)setCustomButtonStyle:(UIButton *)button cornerRadius:(float) cornerRadius fromColor:(UIColor *)fromColor toColor:(UIColor *)toColor normalTitleColor:(UIColor *)normalTitleColor highlightedTitleColor:(UIColor *)highlightedTitleColor borderWidth:(float) borderWidth borderColor:(UIColor*)borderColor
 {
   //Set Title color as you want
   [button setTitleColor:normalTitleColor forState:UIControlStateNormal];
   [button setTitleColor:highlightedTitleColor forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

   //check gradientlayer exist
   id layer = nil;
   if (button.layer.sublayers.count > 0) {
     layer = [button.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0];
   }
   //Find added gradient layer
   CAGradientLayer *addedGradLayer = nil;
   if (layer) {
     if ([layer isKindOfClass:[CAGradientLayer class]]) {
        addedGradLayer = (CAGradientLayer *)[button.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0];
     }
   }

   //check gradient layer exists
   if (!addedGradLayer) //first time
   {
      CAGradientLayer *gradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
      gradientLayer.frame = button.layer.bounds;
      gradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                            (id)fromColor.CGColor,
                            (id)toColor.CGColor,
                            nil];
    
      gradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                               [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                               nil];
    
      gradientLayer.cornerRadius = button.layer.cornerRadius;
      [button.layer insertSublayer:gradientLayer atIndex:0];
      button.clipsToBounds = YES;
   }
   else //next time
   {
    
      CAGradientLayer *newGradientLayer = [CAGradientLayer layer];
      newGradientLayer.frame = button.layer.bounds;
      newGradientLayer.colors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               (id)fromColor.CGColor,
                               (id)toColor.CGColor,
                               nil];
    
      newGradientLayer.locations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f],
                                  [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0f],
                                  nil];
    
      newGradientLayer.cornerRadius = button.layer.cornerRadius;
      [button.layer replaceSublayer:addedGradLayer with:newGradientLayer];
    }
 }

@end
```

Comment: This won't work as I believe the title and image of a button are actually sublayers of the button's layer. So `button.layer.sublayers.count` will always be greater than zero.

Comment: Again, this edit won't work. `button.layer.sublayers` will always have something in it. Whether it is a title or image or gradient layer. Doing `[button.layer.sublayers objectAtIndex:0]` will always return something. But it may not always be a gradient layer.

Comment: LOL! This will work. But I'd rather just use a category and store the layer in a property and only have one set of code to update.

Comment: It reminds me of this... http://cdn.themetapicture.com/media/funny-software-engineer-comic.jpg

Comment: This piece of code can be used even without remembering which layer added.

Comment: Yes, but I like elegant solutions. This problem is the very reason that Categories exist in Objective-C.

Comment: What (for instance) if there is another function somewhere that messes around with the layers of the button and adds another layer somewhere? Maybe it might add a masking layer beneath the gradient layer to change the shape of the button. If that happens then this code would break.